# Power BI - Measure where all filters but one persist / ignore filter by a certain column

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I'm still learning Power BI, so I'm going to use this as a learning opportunity. I'm sure the answer may exist on the web, but I can't seem to find a succinct answer.

I have a table called HW

```
PCNames          Site         ...
Computer1        Site A       ... has software x installed
Computer2        Site B       ... 
Computer3        Site A       ... does not have software x installed.
```

The idea behind this report is to allow managers to review a count of how many machines within their site use each specific piece of software that we support.

The report contains a table with all supported softwares. We'd like for the report to filter the count of machines by the softwares selected in the table. However, we'd like to maintain a total count of assets from that site, regardless of software installed or not.

The problem summary is that I'd like to maintain a total count of machines that remains filterable by all columns, except the current software selection from the table.

Using my example above, in the case of software x being selected on the visual table with Site A selected in a slicer, I'd like for two metrics to display:
Total Assets: 2 (Two total machines from Site A)
Total Assets with software x: 1 (1 machine from Site A with Software X)

I currently have the following broken code:

```
Total Asset Count = Calculate(DistinctCount('HW'[PCName]),Filter(All('HW'), 
****keep all filters, except by software**** ))
```

How can I accomplish this without explicitly defining parameters for each possible filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ignore a filter on a specific column, you can use ALL(Table[Column]):

```
Total Asset Count = Calculate(DistinctCount('HW'[PCName]),ALL(HW[Software]))
```

Comment: ugh, so simple. I didn't realize you could use ALL as a filter like that. I thought Calculate() overwrote all filters with the ones defined in the parameters. Thank you.

Comment: @ssoong And don't forget about `ALLSELECTED()` if you want to only remove the table context filtering, but preserve any slicer filtering.

Comment: How would I configure such formula so my filter on the measure selects a specific value (lets say High) but ignore the same filter from the report level? so if I select Low, the High value calculated in the measure still displays the same?